# (num)pythonic way to make 3d meshes for line plotting

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a line between two points in 3d space:

```
origin = np.array((0,0,0),'d')
final = np.array((1,2,3),'d')
delta = final-origin
npts = 25
points np.array([origin + i*delta for i in linspace(0,1,npts)])
```

But this is silly: I build a big python list and then pass it into numpy, when I'm sure there's a way to do this with numpy alone. How do the numpy wizards do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use [np.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
In [71]: %timeit np.column_stack((np.linspace(o,f,npts) for o,f in zip(origin,final)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 45 us per loop
```

---

```
In [77]: %timeit np.array([origin + i*delta for i in np.linspace(0,1,npts)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 us per loop
```

---

Note: Jaime's answer is faster:

```
In [92]: %timeit origin + (final-origin)*np.linspace(0, 1, npts)[:, np.newaxis]
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.1 us per loop
```

Comment: Second time in one day you've bailed me out! That's very cute, and it never would have occurred to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do away with all Python loops for this one with a little broadcasting:

```
origin + delta*np.linspace(0, 1, npts)[:, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: @Rick: This is faster than my answer. Perhaps you should accept this one.

Comment: @unubtu Only for small values of `npts`. On my system, with `npts = 1000` they run in the same time, and with `npts = 10000` yours is twice as fast. But if you re-write my code as `(origin[:, None] + (final-origin)[:, None]*np.linspace(0, 1, npts)).T` it speeds up considerably, and runs twice as fast as yours for every value of `npts`. The mysteries of memory access...